# Grunt build inside Docker Container returned a Non-zero code: 6

Tags: node.js, docker, gruntjs, dockerfile, ubuntu-16.04

I have been meeting a problem when I'm trying to build a docker container. My docker file is like

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
# ... RUN apt-get update && install ...

EXPOSE 3005

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN npm install forever -g && \
    npm install -g bower && \
    npm install -g grunt-cli
COPY . .
RUN npm install && bower install --allow-root
RUN grunt build

WORKDIR /usr/src/app/dist
CMD NODE_ENV=${APP_ENV} forever start --uid "my_app" --append server/app.js
```

it will produce `The command '/bin/sh -c grunt build' returned a non-zero code: 6`

I have checked from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33961214/docker-run-fails-with-returned-a-non-zero-code-6) and speculating it might be related to `~/.known_host` but I'm still working around to do the same approach. Could you please help how to fix?

For your information, docker stops at `injector` step and this was defined like below

```
injector: {
      options: {

      },
      // Inject application script files into index.html (doesn't include bower)
      scripts: {
        options: {
          transform: function(filePath) {
            filePath = filePath.replace('/client/', '');
            filePath = filePath.replace('/.tmp/', '');
            return '<script src="' + filePath + '"></script>';
          },
          starttag: '<!-- injector:js -->',
          endtag: '<!-- endinjector -->'
        },
        files: {
          '<%= yeoman.client %>/index.html': [
              ['{.tmp,<%= yeoman.client %>}/{app,components}/**/*.js',
               '!{.tmp,<%= yeoman.client %>}/app/app.js',
               '!{.tmp,<%= yeoman.client %>}/{app,components}/**/*.spec.js',
               '!{.tmp,<%= yeoman.client %>}/{app,components}/**/*.mock.js']
            ]
        }
      },

      // Inject component scss into app.scss
      sass: {
        options: {
          transform: function(filePath) {
            filePath = filePath.replace('/client/app/', '');
            filePath = filePath.replace('/client/components/', '');
            return '@import \'' + filePath + '\';';
          },
          starttag: '// injector',
          endtag: '// endinjector'
        },
        files: {
          '<%= yeoman.client %>/app/app.scss': [
            '<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.{scss,sass}',
            '!<%= yeoman.client %>/app/app.{scss,sass}'
          ]
        }
      },

      // Inject component css into index.html
      css: {
        options: {
          transform: function(filePath) {
            filePath = filePath.replace('/client/', '');
            filePath = filePath.replace('/.tmp/', '');
            return '<link rel="stylesheet" href="' + filePath + '">';
          },
          starttag: '<!-- injector:css -->',
          endtag: '<!-- endinjector -->'
        },
        files: {
          '<%= yeoman.client %>/index.html': [
            '<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.css'
          ]
        }
      }
    },
```

Comment: I do not see the definition of APP_ENV in your Dockerfile, so...

Comment: I will pass when i run docker container like `docker run my_image -e APP_ENV=prod`

Comment: No, you can not do that, the build needs this environment variable defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can find in the grunt,[manual](http://gruntjs.com/api/exit-codes) you have 6 status code, because you have a warning.

Posiable solutions are:

1. Fix the warning.
2. `grunt build` => `grunt build --force`